# Disable "New Bookmark" in Nautilus during drag+drop

Tags: nautilus

I often drag files into bookmarked folders within Nautilus after downloading them. However, as I drag the file over the bookmark pane, the folders all shift down by one so that the "+ New Bookmark" option can appear atop the list. Obviously, this makes it difficult to land the drag+dropped file in the appropriate bookmarked folder.

So, I'm looking for one of two solutions:

1. Force the "+ New Bookmark" option to the bottom of the bookmarks pane list when it appears
2. Disable the "+ New Bookmark" option altogether, since there are many other ways to add bookmarks anyways

Hopefully there is a .config/ solution?  Thanks in advance.

Versions: Ubuntu 16.04; GNOME nautilus 3.14.3